# populating obj from XML string after editing or removing few elements , in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I m having following type of content in a string variable

```
<root>

   <head>
   </head>

   <body>

     <head>
     </head>

     <params>
     </params>

   </body>
</root>
```

so either using LINQ or anything else I wish to remove this second **head element that is inside body** tag. so that resultant string becomes like this .

```
<root>

   <head>
   </head>

   <body>

     <params>
     </params>

   </body>
</root>
```

how to do this , is thr any simpler approach rather then string matching or pattern matching approaches.

Thanks in adv guys

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be related to its title....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way on how you can implement what you want.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(""); // use Parse when you have a xml string or use XDocument.Load("") if you have a xml file
var element = doc.Descendants("body").Elements("head"); //selects all head elements that are under body element
if (element != null)
     element.Remove();
string result = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: hey thru this way also the result variable contains same string without removing anything

Comment: but i think if i use this                                              
if (element != null)
     doc.Descendants("body").Elements("head").Remove();
  then perhaps something is possible

Comment: I tested the code that i posted using this string <root>

   <head>
   </head>

   <body>

     <head>
     </head>

     <params>
     </params>

   </body>
</root>. The element was not null (it find a head node uder body element) and was removed. The result string was "<root>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <params></params>
  </body>
</root>"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could read the string into an XmlDocument, locate the offending node and delete it, the serialize the document again.